# flutter http post empty on server side

Tags: php, flutter, dart, flutter-web

i try to send post request in flutter app like

```
static Future<List<dynamic>?> postData(data) async {
    var body = json.encode(data);
    Map<String, String> headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"};
    var url = Uri.http(Config.api, Config.endPoint);
    var response = await client.post(url, headers: headers, body: body);
    if (response.statusCode == 201) {
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      return data;
    }
    return null;
  }
```

this is data was sent

```
Map data = {
      'database': 'school_control_ykt',
      'table': 'tablets_helper',
      'place': place,
      'reason': reason,
      'teacher': teacher,
      'name': name,
      'id_group': id_group
    };
postData(data);
```

but in server side (php) `$_POST` are empty

i wanna know why `$_POST` are empty when a send the request in flutter app but in Postman request is send successfully and `$_POST` have data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voZZj.png)

Comment: Share the log from Postman.

Comment: Why are you JSON-encoding your data? And setting the content type to JSON? Use `var response = await client.post(url, body: data);`

Comment: I had read some solutions and they explain that data must code in JSON and set Content-Type header to application/json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [MultipartRequest](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartRequest-class.html) as API expect `multipart/form-data`. Something like this:

```
var request = MultipartRequest('POST', uri)
  ..fields = data
var response = await request.send();
```